# $PATH vs. $path

Tags: bash, path, zsh

I can't remember why, but a long time ago, I found that for some reason, I needed to set both of these variables.  It caused no problems in bash, but now in zsh, when I put

```
export PATH=~/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export path=$PATH
```

(the same thing I used in .bashrc) in my initialization, I get

```
/Users/…/.zshenv:export:7: path: inconsistent type for assignment
```

**What do they mean by "type," and what is $path used for?**

Comment: `export path=$PATH` is plain nonsense. The error message comes because you want to assign a scalar to an array. The two variables (scalar `PATH` and array `path`) are kept in sync automatically by zsh. My recommendation is to work only with the array, because it is easier typing when you want to add entries to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error mentioning ‘type’ refers to the data type of the variable, such as string or array.

`$PATH` is a string, `$path` is an array. You cannot assign a string, whether by variable or by literal, to a variable typed to contain an array, since the types do not match.

As for what the difference between the two variables are: they are meant to represent the same list of folders, but in different formats. `$PATH` containing `/path/to/one:/path/to/two` would mean that `$path`’s first element is `/path/to/one` and the second one is `/path/to/two`.

You shouldn’t need to manage the two variables (and assigning one to the other won’t work since the types do not match) — the shell should handle it for you. Simply append to the `$PATH` string and the path you add should exist as an element of `$path`.

This only applies in `zsh`, inherited from `*csh`. You can see the ‘binding’ between the two variables with `typeset -p PATH`.

`$path` being an array is really convenient:

- appending and altering the path can be done with array operations like append rather than string manipulation (requiring splitting and joining in the case of editing somewhere in the middle).
- looping through is just `for i ($path) { … }` without needing to deal with the setting of the right split character.

Comment: So, apparently bash automatically converts the types and doesn’t automatically assign both.  I had to put the separate assignment to get something to work long ago.  Don’t remember what.

Comment: So, why do we need both?

Comment: @WGroleau Updated answer

Comment: @WGroleau In bash, `$path` doesn't have any special meaning (and generally doesn't exist). I have no idea why you'd need to set it.

Comment: Well, I can't remember either.  All I remember is that doing so fixed a problem.  But that was at lest a decade ago.  Come to think of it, it might have been in csh.

Comment: @WGroleau : bash does not use `path`, so it's pointless to compare them. I have no idea what csh was doing. I (fortunately) haven't used csh for more than 30 years now.

Answer (score 3):

PATH is a scalar value- a continuous string of search paths separated by colons and path is an array of search paths. `zsh` will sync both path and PATH. There is no need for you to do so.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a nice tip

`print -l $path`

because the type of this variable is an array, more operations are available

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answers the question asked ("What do they mean by "type," and what is $path used for?")?

Comment: Q : "what is $path used for?" A: "print -l $path" Q: "What do they mean by "type,"" A: "something that allows the previous A"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: tough luck, that's what types are for